# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression - POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having an issue while inserting a data to postgres table..

Here  is my query:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_id, user_id) 
SELECT id, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE c_id = _c_id) FROM product_badge WHERE comp_id = _comp_id;
```

Issue I'm receiving is

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   CONTEXT

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are `_c_id` and `_comp_id`? What are you trying to achieve? You should give more context to your question, for example  by providing sample data and expected results.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  Sample data and desired results would help figure out what to do.

Comment: Skip the subquery. Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Before inserting all combination be sure of the functional impact and the business implications. The technically working solution doesn't mean that it is the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first the problem with `limit`:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_id, user_id) 
    SELECT id, (SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.c_id = _c_id LIMIT 1) 
    FROM product_badge
    WHERE comp_id = _comp_id;
```

However, that is a work-around.  Normally in this case, you might want *all* combinations, and that suggests a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO products (product_id, user_id) 
    SELECT pb.id, u.id
    FROM product_badge pb CROSS JOIN
         users u
    WHERE pb.comp_id = _comp_id AND
          u.c_id = _c_id;
```

Comment: This would add/take same user_id for each row im inserting?

Comment: @MateuszRek . . . The first would take an arbitrary matching user id, but probably the same one.  The second would insert rows for all user ids.

Answer (score 0):

MateuszRek,

As long as

```
SELECT id FROM product_badge inner join users WHERE c_id = _c_i
```

returns more than one row you will have a problem.
Using a subquery as selected field implies the engine get the result as the value of that field.
having more rows poses problem as the engine can pick a value

You can us limit to pick one value. However, even if that solves the technical part of the problem,it might leave a functional/business one because maybe something is missing, for example, for to choose that id. using limit doesnt garantee its the right value